# Why images folder is not copied when generating an Octopress with jekyll-assets blog?

Tags: asset-pipeline, jekyll, octopress

I am building an Octopress blog and I am implementing an alternative search implementation, [lunr-search](https://github.com/yortz/octopress-lunr-js-search).

This requires an [asset pipeline implementation for Jekyll](https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets).

My assets, javascripts and CSSs are compiled and combined correctly, but my images folder is not copied to the public folder.

EDIT with further info:

I have my assets under `/source/_assets/javascripts`, `/source/_assets/stylesheets` and `/source/_assets/images`.

The relevant part in `_config.yml`:

```
assets:
  dirname: assets
  baseurl: /assets/
  sources:
    - _assets/javascripts
    - _assets/jwplayer
    - _assets/stylesheets
    - _assets/images
  compress:
    js:
    css:
  cachebust: hard
  gzip: [ text/css, application/javascript ]
```

My compiled and combined assets are generated as expected under `/public/assets`, under which I can find the `app.js` and `screen.css`, however there is no `images` folder.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you provide more information, i.e. how are your directories named and organized?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @agarie. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you rewritten your source to use Jekyll-Assets to render image paths?  In my experience, Jekyll-Assets needs to know you'll be using an asset before it will copy it to the output directory.  It will know when you use a corresponding Liquid tag or filter.

According to the [Jekyll-Assets readme](https://github.com/ixti/jekyll-assets#how-to-use-jekyll-assets), URLs for assets that are neither scripts nor stylesheets may be included with the following Liquid tag:

```
{% asset_path logo.png %}
```

Additionally, the following Liquid filter is available:

```
{{ 'logo.png' | asset_path }}: Returns resulting URL for logo.png
```

Both examples come from the URL above.  So in this case the following two lines would be equivalent:

```
<img src="{% asset_path logo.png %}" alt="Logo">
<img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_path }}" alt="Logo">
```

If you are indeed already doing this, relevant HTML/Liquid source code may prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me

```
{% img /images/logo.png %}
```